# UL's - how to add a header at the top?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have two UL's:

[image]

How can I add text to appear in the top green area.

The text needs to not be in an LI.

Every attempt I make has the text appear outside the boxes.  I've had the two UL's wrapped in both a div and a span (currently a span as below) with text before the UL but but neither helped and the text was still outside.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gThjy/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    #list_to_process, #categories  {   
      color: blue; background-color: green; border: solid; 
      border-width: 4px; padding-top:40px
    }   
    .panel { color: red; background-color: yellow; 
             border: solid; border-width: 4px }
    ul { padding: 10px; margin: 50px; float:left; list-style:none; }
    li { color: yellow; padding: 25px 80px; cursor: move; }
    li:nth-child(even) { background-color: #000 }
    li:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #666 }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="a_list">
      header1
      <ul id="list_to_process">
        <li class="to_process" id="left1">1</li>
        <li class="to_process" id="left2">2</li>
        <li class="to_process" id="left3">3</li>
        <li class="to_process" id="left4">4</li>
        <li class="to_process" id="left5">5</li>
      </ul>
    </span>
    <span class="a_list">
      <ul id="categories">
        <li id="righta">a</li>
        <li id="rightb">b</li>
        <li id="rightc">c</li>
        <li id="rightd">d</li>
        <li id="righte">e</li>
      </ul>
    </span>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just use positioning http://jsfiddle.net/gThjy/6/

Comment: That markup is invalid: spans can only contain inline elements

Answer (score 1):

With your current markup this addition to CSS will work and be semantic:

```
#list_to_process:before, #categories:before{ 
content:"Read this: ";
}
```

Comment: Demos are a really good way to show that your answer works:  http://jsfiddle.net/gThjy/7/

Answer (score 0):

Well its only valid in HTML to have an `<li>` as a child of a `<ul>` or `<ol>` so wrapping any text in a different element isn't possible. You can simply just add text directly after the starting tag for the `<ul>` and it'll show up in the green area, though I'm not sure thats exactly what you're after. I'm also unsure of whether its valid to have a text-node directly after a `<ul>` tag, though I will try to find a source.

http://jsfiddle.net/PerfectDark/gThjy/5/

**Update**: Adding text before the starting `<ul>` tag is also invalid according to the validator:

*Line 38, Column 10: Text not allowed in element ul in this context.*

I think your best option is to absolutely position an element to have it appear its inside the box.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

```
  <ul id="list_to_process">
      Header 1
    <li class="to_process" id="left1">1</li>
    <li class="to_process" id="left2">2</li>
    <li class="to_process" id="left3">3</li>
    <li class="to_process" id="left4">4</li>
    <li class="to_process" id="left5">5</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="categories">
      Header 2
    <li id="righta">a</li>
    <li id="rightb">b</li>
    <li id="rightc">c</li>
    <li id="rightd">d</li>
    <li id="righte">e</li>
  </ul>
```